# How do I insert a record with the key of the previous record in one call?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In my database, I have a table called `Department` that columns named `DepartmentID` (PK) and `SubdepartmentOfID` (FK). SubdepartmentOfID is constrained as a FK to `DepartmentID` in order to basically create a hierarchical type relationship.

What I'm trying to do in Entity Framework 6 is to create a default subdepartment that has the same name as the department, but in order to do so, I need to be able to set the SubdepartmentOfID before inserting it though my context, right? Currently, I'm using this logic:

- Create the entity, insert it, save it (this ends up populating the DepartmentID key in the entity).
- Create another entity for the subdepartment and set its SubdepartmentOfID property equal to that of the previously saved entity, save it

I feel like this could be done in one call. Can it?

Comment: is stored procedure not an option?

Comment: Do you have a collection of `SubDepartments` in the `Department` entity?

Comment: Also what comes to mind is that the top-level `Departments` will have `NULL` `SubdepartmentOfID`. This is not a normalized structure. It might be easier (and more normalized) to place these relationships in another table. Then you would have to do some overriding in EF 6 to keep it nice and clean.

Comment: @mrtig It is an option, but I'm learning Entity Framework and would like to know if it can already handle this situation.

Comment: @KeithPayne Yes it does. I also forgot to mention that I am filling that SubdepartmentOfID with it's own PK for top levels. I'm trying to write it in such a way that I could walk it all the way up 20 levels if needed.

Comment: @KeithPayne This structure is pretty standard when you want to support N number of Parent => Child relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes the following:

- You're using database first (using the designer) as opposed to code first
- You have a table named `Department` with the following columns

  ```
  DepartmentID
  SubDepartmentID
  DepartmentName
  ```

I think you can do this.

```
var department = new Department
                     {
                          DepartmentName = "D1"
                     };

var subDepartment = new Department
                     {
                         DepartmentName = "D1"
                     };

department.Department = subDepartment;
context.Departments.Add(department);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Entity framework will now take care of the autogenerated IDs and associate the sub department to the department.

Comment: So please suggest some edits, that would really be helpful to both me and anyone else looking at it.

Comment: I think this is something I had in the back of my mind. Will EF take care of Keys then?

Comment: It is missing the relationship declarations (either attributes or code-first). It is using a natural key for the relationship when the OP is using surrogate keys. `DepartmentName` is incorrectly declared as an `int`.

Comment: @KeithPayne I fixed the minor mistakes. And I'm assuming it's not code first as the poster didn't specify. Not sure why you are claiming major errors?

Comment: Correct, I am using database first

Comment: @Sinaesthetic So you should have a foreign key to the same table which should expose a property on `Department` named `Department` I would assume.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, Muffin - This doesn't answer the question as the OP phrased it. Also, marking up the entity class is key to making it work and the markup isn't present. I understand what you are trying to express. However, I am not convinced that EF will do what the code implies. This Q needs a working sample to prove the answer, IMO.

Comment: I took what you were getting at and it does work. By creating the Department, then inserting a new department in to the navigation property, inserting, then saving, it does what I wanted with the keys :)

Comment: @Sinaesthetic please show the attributes on the class that makes this work. I think that it will be helpful as a permanent answer.

Comment: @KeithPayne As i mentioned a few comments earlier, I am using database first. I am using the classes generated by the edmx and they contain no attributes.

Comment: @KeithPayne Let me edit my question to mention that it's not code first.